DataByte to List<int> using map function?
I have a buffer byteBuffer in ByteData format that is 500 bytes long.  It's a list of 250 Uint16 values.  I can convert it to List using a loop with the following code (and it works).
List<int> data = [];

// Convert ByteData to List<int>
for (var i = 0; i < 500; i += 2) {
   data.add(byteBuffer.getUint16(i, Endian.little));
}

If I wanted to convert the List of int into a List of double, I can use a map function as follows:
var doubleData = data.map((i) => i.toDouble()).toList();

I'm wondering if there is a way to create a map function to go from the ByteData to List of int without using the loop?
I've tried doing stuff like:
List<int> data = byteBuffer.map((i) => i.getUint16(i, Endian.little)).toList();

But map is not defined for ByteData.  Is there a way to map it or do something similar, other than using a loop?

Have you tried this? List<int> data = byteBuffer.asUint16List();

Doesn't work.  "The method 'asUint16List' isn't defined for the type 'ByteData'."

I guess I assumed byteBuffer was a ByteBuffer based on the variable name. You can try List<int> data = byteBuffer.buffer.asUint16List();

Yes, that works!  Thank you!  That's far more simple than the loop or another method I got it work: List<int> data = List<int>.generate(byteBuffer.lengthInBytes - 2 >> 1, (i) {return byteBuffer.getUint16(i * 2, Endian.little);});
